# Nonlinear ARDL model with multiple decmoposed variables

Tags: r, ardl

For my master thesis, I would like to run a nonlinear ardl model with more than one decomposed variables. However, I wasn't able to find any function in R which allows to define more than one decomposed variable. I am wondering whether it is in general possible to include multiple variables with a positive and a negative coefficient at the same time. If not, is it at least possible to include the other variables in a linear way?

Would highly appreciate any comment on that! :-)

I tried both, including other decomposed and other "control" variables with the nardl_auto_case function and the nardl function in R.
I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com) but I wasn't able to make the model work.